# Remove View from parent, animate others into place?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a `LinearLayout` that, throughout the course of the application, aggregates child views that can be removed. My question is, when a child is removed from a parent view, is there any way to animate the other children into place? In essence, I want to sort of recreate the effect of the ICS/Jelly Bean recent apps window - when one is swiped away the others sort of fall into place. I know that this specific implementation is made by Google and thus is probably outside the realm of possibilities that I can do, but how would I go about emulating that effect?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Read about viewgroup animation in this answer. You can use animation API to create animation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524820/940680